# Recursive function for a binary search

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-search

Create a recursive function for the binary search.
This function accepts a sorted array and an item to search for, and returns the index of the item (if item is in the array), or returns -1 (if item is not in the array).
Moreover, write a test program to test your function.

```
template <class elemType>
int orderedArrayListType<elemType>::binarysearch
                                (const elemType& item) const
{
    int first= 0;
    int last = length -1;
    int mid;
    int list[];
    int BinarySearch(,Type & Item, int first, int last)
    bool found = false;
    while (first <= last && !found){
        mid = (first + last) / 2;
        if (list[mid] > item)
            return BinarySearch(list, item, first, mid -1)
        found = true;
        else if (list[mid] > item)
            return BinarySearch( list, item, first, mid -1)
            last = mid - 1;
        else 
            first = mid + 1;
    }
    if (found)
        return mid;
    else 
        return -1;
}
```

Comment: The deal here is that you write your own homework solutions, asking us about specific problems you are having with the code.

Comment: It must be that time of year.

Comment: Did the tutor not know, or did he not want to do your assignment for you?

Comment: Ask your teacher to explain the problem in whatever language you normally communicate and then translate it for us.

Comment: I speak english she does not haha but i re-edited my question and posted what I have done so far thanks for the help with a newbie on this website

Comment: Upvoting because you did the right thing as suggested by others.  Glad to have you on SO.

Answer (score 7):

There's a child's game in the USA where one child picks a number between 1 and 10, and the other child has to guess that number.  If they guess wrong, the first child says "higher" or "lower".

Most kids start out guessing randomly, and will take about 4-5 tries on average to succeed.  I realized (and this is probably why I ended up in computer science), that the best thing to do is pick the mid point (5.5, so pick either 5 or 6.  I'll go with 5.).  Based on what they say ("higher" or "lower"), select a new range, either 1-4 or 6-10.  Pick the number in the middle of that range (2 or 8).  Keep splitting the range in half until you get the number.

That's a binary search on a sorted array (the sorted array being numbers from 1 to 10).

To implement that in code, just keep doing the same process described above.  Pick the midpoint of the range, and create a new range based on the answer.

Here's [one solution in Java](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.lang/recursive-binary-search-implementation-in-java.html) that does this recurvively:

```
public class BinarySearchRecursive
{
    public static final int NOT_FOUND = -1;

    /**
     * Performs the standard binary search
     * using two comparisons per level.
     * This is a driver that calls the recursive method.
     * @return index where item is found or NOT_FOUND if not found.
     */
    public static int binarySearch( Comparable [ ] a, Comparable x )
    {
        return binarySearch( a, x, 0, a.length -1 );
    }

    /**
     * Hidden recursive routine.
     */
    private static int binarySearch( Comparable [ ] a, Comparable x,
                                     int low, int high )
    {
        if( low > high )
            return NOT_FOUND;

        int mid = ( low + high ) / 2;

        if( a[ mid ].compareTo( x ) < 0 )
            return binarySearch( a, x, mid + 1, high );
        else if( a[ mid ].compareTo( x ) > 0 )
            return binarySearch( a, x, low, mid - 1 );
        else
            return mid;
    }

    // Test program
    public static void main( String [ ] args )
    {
        int SIZE = 8;
        Comparable [ ] a = new Integer [ SIZE ];


    for( int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++ )
        a[ i ] = new Integer( i * 2 );

    for( int i = 0; i < SIZE * 2; i++ )
        System.out.println( "Found " + i + " at " +
                                 binarySearch( a, new Integer( i ) ) );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also [google](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=recursive+binary+search&aq=f&aqi=g9g-m1&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) "recursive binary search" and [voila](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search#Recursive)!

**EDIT-** Wikipedia knows all (especially when it comes to cs):

> The most straightforward
>   implementation [of the binary search algorithm] is recursive, which
>   recursively searches the subrange
>   dictated by the comparison:

```
   BinarySearch(A[0..N-1], value, low, high) {
       if (high < low)
           return -1 // not found
       mid = low + ((high - low) / 2) 
       if (A[mid] > value)
           return BinarySearch(A, value, low, mid-1)
       else if (A[mid] < value)
           return BinarySearch(A, value, mid+1, high)
       else
           return mid // found
   }
```

Comment: No he did not know either =).  I have been working on this thing for a week but we have yet to go over Binary Search's but as i speak we are going over them now so i hope to get some sort of hint to what the heck im supposed to do

Answer (score -1):

Just use [std::binary_search](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/binary_search/). Tell the tutor that function is actually implemented recursively in your_favorite_compiler.

Comment: -1, this answer is deliberately obtuse. Tutors set tasks to enable learning, not to try to get their students to replace library functions. Perhaps maths students shouldn't be taught anything which can be done on a calculator?

Comment: @JBentley - so was the question in its initial form. Being aware of library functions doesn't hurt anyway.